# Sanity check -> проверка на вшивость?

Tags: перевод

Перевод *sanity check* -> *проверка на вшивость* напрашивается сам собой. Однако словари ничего про это не знают. Они предпочитают кучу странных вариантов, типа *санитарная проверка*, *проверка работоспособности* (как будто проверка на вшивость не является санитарной и можно проверить работоспособность поверхностной санитарной проверкой) кроме этого.

По-моему проверка на вшивость как и санитарная проверка это нечто поверхностное, поверхностная проверка работоспособности. Перевод в обратную сторону показывает *integrity check*. Проверка целостности это то же самое, как я понимаю -- поверхностный тест работоспособности. Только в контексте sanity наверное лучше брать не "целостность" а "вшивость", чтобы дух исходной фразы тоже передать. Нет?

Comment: Проверка на вшивость - это чаще всего проверка человека на отсутствие подозрительных связей. Да и программы, которым делают sanity check, не страдают вшивостью ни в буквальном, ни а переносном смысле.

Comment: @Taosique То есть у технических систем может быть гигиена, но не может быть подозрительных связей? Почему тогда переводят проверка на вшивость -> integrity check? Если вы говорите что у программ не может быть никакой вшивости, то integrity check это термин из биологии получается или это ошибка в словаре?

Comment: Где "проверка на вшивость" переводят как integrity check?

Comment: @Alex.S Вы правы. Я проверил -- нигде. Там оказалось `integrity test`, что к `integrity check`, к моему великому изумлению, оказалось связано с проверкой моральных принципов потенциального работника, а никак не железаячки. Снимаю шляпу. Удалить вопрос?

Comment: можно попробовать термин - "рабочий прогон"

Comment: Проверка на БЕЗУМИЕ!!!111!1

Answer (score 10):

"Sanity" does not have anything in common with personal hygiene. "Sane" means "sound", "reasonable": an insane person is not dirty, they are crazy.

Sanity check is a basic test for absence of, well, insane things in your product. If a car engine part under heavy load is made of a wrong alloy, it might not pass functional tests; if it's made of cheap plastic held together by a piece of duct tape, it would fail the sanity check. It's insane to make engine parts of duct tape and plastic, and there is no need to even bother putting it under load.

Depending on context it might be translated as *испытание здравым смыслом*, *проверка на разумность* etc.

*Проверка на вшивость* is usually applied to people. Its result is revealing the person's true self, whether or not they would expose their dark side under extreme conditions.

Comment: Вообще-то я проверил этимологию и ваше утверждение "sanity не имеет отношения к гигиене" немного не соответствует действительности. Как _гигиена_ так _здравомыслие_ происходят от слова здравость, исправность. Утверждать что они не имеют ничего общего это всё равно что отрицать общее начало между братьями, что согласитесь не очень здраво.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov: those words are etymologically related, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Есть несколько уровней проверки программы на работоспособность. Smoke check и Sanity check два наиболее поверхностных. Проваленный "Тест на дым" - это если при запуске программы она сразу же выдает сообщение об ошибке (в электронике - если аппарат включенный в розетку начинает дымить).

Тест на "вменяемость" - это если программа внешне выглядит рабочей и вроде бы способна выполнять ожидаемые функции. Более подробной проверки не делается - т.е. не обязательно чтобы данные считались правильно и т.п. Это простой поверхностный осмотр того что окошки открываются, кнопки нажимаются.

Integrity check - обычно это проверка целостности файлов. Есть еще integration testing - это совершенно другой уровень проверки. Обычно это проверка на совместную работу различных компонентов программы, которые разрабатывались отдельно. Например отдельно разрабатывался ввод данных в программу и отдельно - вывод отчетов на принтер. По отдельности они работают, но работают ли они вместе - это должна показать проверка на интеграцию.

Так что это не "санитарная" проверка, а проверка "на здравомыслие".

Answer (score 6):

Как бывший тестер:

Вообще-то, учитывая отсылку к program bugs, "проверка программы на вшивость" звучит очень неплохо.

Однако дух фразы sanity check "проверка на вшивость" как раз НЕ передаёт.
Во-первых, "sanity check" применяется и в формальнoй среде, а вот "результат проверки на вшивость" в отчёте звучит немного по-хулигански.
И, во-вторых, "проверка на вшивость" предполгает аккуратный поиск конкретной проблемы, а sanity check, наоборот, с наименьшей дотошностью проверяет общую работоспособность. Даже грязная и забагованная программа, связанная с самыми  подозрительными библиотеками, может пройти sanity check.